# Como ocultar un valor null de un TD en html

Tags: html, datatables

Tnego una tabla que me muestra datos 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que quiero es qu cuando aun no este asignado el responsable no me muestre null , simplemente no me muestre nada , en cambio cuando este asignado me lo muestre .

```
 filas+="<td>"+resultados[i].nResponsable+"</td>";
            filas+="<td>Ventaja: "+resultados[i].Ventaja+"<br> Desventaja: "+resultados[i].Desventaja+"</td>";
            filas+="<td><div class='control-group' style='margin-bottom: 0px; '><textarea id='tbComentario_"+resultados[i].cod_requerimiento+"'  name='tbComentario_"+resultados[i].cod_requerimiento+"'></textarea></div></td>";
            filas+="<td>";
            filas+="    <button type='button' data-id="+resultados[i].cod_requerimiento+" id='btnA_"+resultados[i].cod_requerimiento+"' class='btn btn-primary envio aprob'> Aprobar </button>";
            filas+="    <button type='button' data-id="+resultados[i].cod_requerimiento+" id='btnN_"+resultados[i].cod_requerimiento+"' class='btn btn-danger envio neg'> Rechazar</button>";
            filas+="</td>";
```

Este es el código que me arma la tabla.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

lo puedes hacer de diferentes formas desde Javascript y como te menciona **Dismark**.

Para javascript debes verificar si trae un valor lo muestras caso contrario no algo asi:

```
if(resultados[i].nResponsable !==  null){
  filas+="<td>"+resultados[i].nResponsable+"</td>";
}else{
  filas+="<td></td>";
}
```

con este if verificas si trae null no escribes nada mas que tu **td** caso contrario muestras el valor respectivo.

Espero te sirva suerte..!!

Comment: Gracias, Me sirvió bastante :)

Answer (score 2):

No veo la consulta SQL, pero puedes manejar el `NULL` directamente con
un blucle `IF`.

Seria en tu caso a la hora de seleccionar el campo `responsable` en lugar de llamarlo directamente en la `SELECT` usa el bucle:

```
SELECT IF(responsable IS NULL, '', responsable) AS responsable FROM tabla_dela_base_de_datos
```

Un saludo !